# Applying changes to entire dataframe using group by

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply changes to a dataframe for values only returned (to the best of my knowledge) by using groupby. So what I want is to find the minimum date values for each company so that I can apply the number 0 to first value in several columns (in this case df2['Research and Development Expense Lag'] and df2['Capital Expenditures Lag']). Here is what I have so far, a groupby that returns those minimum date values for each company:

```
df2.groupby('Ticker Symbol').apply(lambda d: \
            d[d['Data Date'] == d['Data Date'].min()])
```

Comment: you can use `transform` instead of `apply`

Comment: I provided an answer below, but am not sure exactly what you mean by "apply to *first* value".  Are there multiple rows where date is the minimum?  If so, how do you plan to identify the *first* row?  A good question on Stack Overflow should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with sample input and expected output.

Comment: See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You can get the index values for those rows and then use them with `.loc[]` to change values in those two columns:

```
df2.loc[df2.groupby('Ticker Symbol').apply(
        lambda d: d[d['Data Date'] == d['Data Date'].min()]
    )
    .index
    .get_level_values(1),
    ['Research and Development Expense Lag', 'Capital Expenditures Lag']
] = 0
```

The `.get_level_values(1)` function serves to extract the second level of the MultiIndex.  The first level will contain `Ticker Symbol` values.